# Android NDK Default location

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk

I am used to previous versions of NDK builds which came in zip format. I downloaded the recent `r10` version for windows which had a .exe version. The exe version is just an extractor, that I didn't know and double clicked it. It didn't ask me for the location of extraction.

Now I want to remove this version and use a zip instead. How do I find on which location it was installed/extracted?

I tried looking to the `ANDROID_NDK` system variable and I found my previous definition of r8 version.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The latest version extracts itself inside the current working directory. So if you launched it from the explorer, that's the same directory as your .exe.

You should find an `android-ndk-rXXX` folder there. Otherwise that means it wasn't extracted.

It's always better to use the latest NDK, there are many bug fixes and improvements with each releases... You can open the .exe as an archive with 7zip, and extract it somewhere else if you need, or launch the .exe from a terminal set where you want to have it extracted.

Comment: Actually I have launched it from a Download Manager and it was extracted inside its program files folder. That's why I was not able to find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 44):

Android Studio 2.2 installs it in `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle` (on Windows 10).

Comment: Obviously, "Dev" in C:\Users\Dev refers to your current account name.

Answer (score 23):

I am using Visual Studio, but I also want to play with Android Studio.  So, in order to get the Android SDK and NDK, I installed Android Studio.

**The Answer**

Android Studio installed the SDK naturally at

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

The NDK folder is not yet ready, but is/will exist at

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle
```

In order to flush out the folder with the actual NDK, I had to tell Android Studio to install the NDK.

File -> Settings

Select Appearance and Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK

Click on the SDK Tools Tab

Checkbox the NDK (And, I think, the LLDB and CMake options).

Select Apply/Install.

Now that NDK folder should be good to go.

Answer (score 15):

in MacOs Android Studio installs it in

```
"/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle"
```

change USERNAME with your username.

Answer (score 10):

### **`For Windows Android Studio 2.3.x(+):`**

My `android-sdk` folder was in `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android-ndk`

**Be careful:** The ndk might not be complete, so make sure everything is up to date.

Answer (score 6):

Windows 10 and Internet Download Manager thew mine into C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\IDM

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10, It landed in

C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Windows\SysWOW64\android-ndk-r10e

Answer (score 2):

If you install from Android studio and not by downloading manually, you will find it in:

> C:{Whatever place you had your root android installed}sdk\ndk-bundle

the path depends on where you had your root sdk folder installed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on Ubuntu and it was installed to the subdirectory /home/username/Android/Sdk/ndk in my Android SDK directory.

I had to install the NDK from the Android Studio File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK - SDK Tools location.

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the install location of Android SDK, then in your custom Android SDK location search for **ndk** folder. You will find NDK installation with required version.

Answer (score -2):

I Downloaded the NDK From within Unity.
It arrived in my Downloads folder.
C:\Users[USERNAME]\Downloads\android-ndk-r10e-windows-x86_64.exe

(select the ndk-r10e folder in downloads).