# Where is android-ndk located?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-ndk, visual-studio-2017

I installed Visual Studio 2017. In the Installer menu, I've installed Xamarin and Visual C#. However, when I created a new project, went to Tools > Options > Xamarin , I saw that the android-ndk textbox is empty whereas the others are not.

I've installed Visual Studio on this path: D:\Program Files\Visual Studio. But I don't know if it will put the installation of Xamarin to the D:\

My question is where is android-ndk?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522184/android-ndk-default-location and https://www.google.com/search?q=Android+-+Where+is+android-ndk+located?+site:stackoverflow.com&client=ubuntu&hs=IX1&channel=fs&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjC2MjvkrfdAhUGTbwKHfJAC24QrQIoBDALegQIBRAM&biw=1320&bih=666

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android NDK Default location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522184/android-ndk-default-location)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For Visual Studio, the [default NDK location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/android-sdk-location?tabs=vswin) is:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b
```

For Android Studio, the default NDK location is:

```
C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle
```

---

**But by default, Visual Studio won't download Android NDK**. So if you need download Android NDK, you could go to [VS Tools tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=vswin#tools-tab):

```
Tools > Android > Open Android SDK Manager > select Tools > Check NDK > Click Apply Changes
```

[image]

Comment: FWIW, I've never been able to successfully download NDK via Visual Studio's version of Android SDK manager (after downloading all the bytes, get "Download Failed".) Just tried again today on a new PC with a fresh install of VS 2017 & Xamarin Android. Anyway, can download manually at https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/ - Then set NDK location to wherever you install (unzip) that download, via VS Tools/ Options/ Xamarin/ Android NDK Location.

Comment: In Visual Studio, NDK is installed by Visual Studio Installer into %PROGRAMDATA%/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/